# Magento - how to extend login session time on php.ini or htacess

Tags: login, session

I'm user of Magento and out website is supported by web hosting company, simplehelix.

I want to extend our website session time because the remaining time of login is too short.
I already set the time on Magento back-end server but it didn't work. 
I saw this phase like

> Magento will rely on session.gc_maxlifetime, despite what you've set in the store admin area.

So i tried to update php.ini or htacess file but htacess file doesn't have **gc_maxlifetime** value. I found the php.ini file but it was an back-up file. So i create own php.ini file and modify the gc_maxlifetime to 10800(about 3 hrs).However, i'm facing on the same situation.

By searching on Google, lots of programmers said that when setting on php.ini is changed, The restart of server is needed. So could i ask the web hosting company or is there any other way to apply this new set up? Thank you so much.

Comment: It works ! If you have an issue like that, Try it !

Comment: **Solution for beginner** - In order to access these file, you need linux server like putty. Go login and write code like "cd  /usr/local/lib/php.ini." on command. And you can edit the codes with vim or vi. So you should chage the gc_maxlifetime value. Not use back-up file. Because already exsit php.ini file on your web server. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing you can do is configure session timeout value from the backend.
For Magento 2,

```
Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Admin->Security
```

and find the entry named `Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)` and untick the checkbox then you can enter custom value. Insert time period you want to automatically locked in seconds (Ex-3600 for one hour) and click `Save Config`